# Kotlin and Mockito - mocking function call to super class

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I am having some issues with Mockito and stubbing out methods that uses a class as a parameter in Kotlin.

I have a few classes defined as follows:

```
open interface interfaceFile {
  fun someFun(param1: String): String
} 

abstact class abstractClass {
  abstract val variable1: RandomType

  open fun<T> getObject(param1: String, param2: Class<T>, vararg param3: Any): T? {
    doSomeStuff()
}

open class concreteClass @Autowired constructor(
    override val variable1: RandomType
  ): abstractClass(), interfaceFile {

    override fun someFun(param1: String): String {
      return getObject(param1, string::Class.java)!!

}
```

Then I tried to use mockito to mock the `getObject` function and test it as follows:

```
fun setUp() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this)
  testObject = mock(concreteClass::class.java)
}

fun testSomeFun() {
  `when`(testObject!!.getObject("string1", String::class.java)).thenReturn("Mocked")
  val actualResponse = testObject!!.someFun("string1")
  assertEquals("message", "Mocked", actualResponse)
}
```

In short, `concreteClass.someFun` will call the `abstractClass.getObject` which will call `doSomeStuff`.  But during testing I want to stub out `abstractClass.getObject` to just return.  But the current behavior seems to be that I always get `null` instead.

I've simplified it to the point where it takes a single string parameter and stubbing it out then works, but seems when I introduce the class type as a parameter it stops working.

Search around it seems like my issue has to do with incorrect argument matching in my `when` call, but I can't figure out whats wrong with it since I even put in exact values instead of using ArgumentMatchers.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `someFun` method is from interface, so we can say it is `open` too. Thats why in mock it's overriding with returning null. To make it call basic code write following:

```
`when`(testObject!!.someFun("string1")).thenCallRealMethod()
```

By the way. Why your `testObject` is nullable? Set it `lateinit var testObject: concreteClass` to initialize it in `setUp` function.